# Reading a column containing commas into AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am downloading a file from a 3rd-party service in csv format and saving it to AWS S3. I'm trying to read it into an Athena table using the OpenCSVSerde decoder. The records are unfortunately not very clean, and so some rows have names and others do not. For those that do have names, they can have 2 or 3 components (i.e. some names are missing a middle name). When I run the table create statement below, the columns are shifted to the right when the row contains a name.  Is there a way to get athena to recognize the triple quoted value as a block, and not split those values on the comma?

File Extract

```
Date,Agent Name,Agent ID,Campaign Name,Skill Name
2023/09/28,,,,
2023/09/28,"""Last", Middle," First""",,,
2023/09/28,"""Last2", Middle2," First2""",,,
```

Table DDL Statement

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
    `date` string,
    `agent_name` string,
    `agent_id` string,
    `campaign_name` string,
    `skill_name` string,
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'quoteChar' = '"""',
    'escapeChar' = '\\',
    'separatorChar' = ','
)
LOCATION 's3://{bucket-name}/{report-name}/extracts/'
tblproperties ('skip.header.line.count' = '1');
```

Athena results:

[image]

I've tried changing the OpenCSVSerde properties, with no change.

Comment: Hi Katie, you mention *I've tried changing the OpenCSVSerde properties, with no change.* - can you share what you've tried and what the output was? Have you tried `"quoteChar" = '""'` or even `"quoteChar" = '"""'`?

Comment: Here are the options I've tried: "quoteChar" = '"', "quoteChar" = '""', "quoteChar" = '"""', "quoteChar" = '\"', "quoteChar" = '\""', "quoteChar" = '\"""'. For each of those attempts, the output still looked like the screenshot above- with the three names split into separate columns.